# CSS Responsive-ness doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make this page responsive but after many fails I'm stuck. Can anyone tell me why there is a white border at the top and also the images aren't fitting the page?

CSS:

```
.cb-slideshow,
.cb-slideshow:after { 
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 0; 
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;  
}
.cb-slideshow:after { 
    content: '';
    margin-top:0px
}
.cb-slideshow li span { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li div { 
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    color: #bf1e2d;
    -webkit-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/spr-banner1.jpg) 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/spr-banner2.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/spr-banner3.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/spr-banner4.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s; 
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) div { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) div { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) div { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s; 
}

/* Animation for the slideshow images */
@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-o-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
/* Animation for the title */
@-webkit-keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    8% { opacity: 1 }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-moz-keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    8% { opacity: 1 }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-o-keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    8% { opacity: 1 }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-ms-keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    8% { opacity: 1 }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    8% { opacity: 1 }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
/* Show at least something when animations not supported */
.no-cssanimations .cb-slideshow li span{
    opacity: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1140px) { 
    .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 140px }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
    .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 80px }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie ie6 no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie ie7 no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie ie8 no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie ie9 no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
        <title>The Social PR | Coming Soon</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <meta name="description" content="The Social PR Coming Soon" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="PR" />
        <meta name="author" content="Zak Lewis" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.86080.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body id="page">
        <ul class="cb-slideshow">
            <li><span>Image 01</span><div></div></li>
            <li><span>Image 02</span><div></div></li>
            <li><span>Image 03</span><div></div></li>
            <li><span>Image 04</span><div></div></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="container">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you require further information to help me please ask me.

Comment: Post the relevant code here.

Comment: I pasted the address so you can see the whole code in action, easier that way but if you want me to paste the same code that's fine with me

Comment: The main reason why we want to see the whole code is that we don't try to solve particular problems. We want to have some solutions that work for a lot of people. What happens if the website won't be available after a while ? The post won't have any value. Thanks for adding those details here. :)

Comment: I understand, apologies, I've added the code.

Answer (score 1):

Give `.cb-slideshow{margin-top:0px}`.
for your background image play with `.cb-slideshow li span{background-position: 50% 50%;}` as you like.

Comment: After couple of refreshes it worked! thanks for your help, just need to fix this responsive issue now any ideas?